# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager custom http header always start with "HTTP_"?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I use AFHTTPRequestOperationManager to send HTTP request, and have some information put in the HTTP custom header, named "X-AKey".
I confirmed the header name by:

```
NSLog(@"%@", manager.requestSerializer.HTTPRequestHeaders);
```

Then, I captured the outgoing message, and found that the header name has changed to "HTTP_X_AKEY".

I've searched some questions, and found that this might be a standard way of naming custom header: "Meta-variables with names beginning with "HTTP_" contain values read from the client request header fields, if the protocol used is HTTP. The HTTP header field name is converted to upper case, has all occurrences of "-" replaced with "*" and has "HTTP*" prepended to give the meta-variable name."

Nevertheless, my question is: **CAN I send a message with a custom header name exactly as I specified? That is, in my case, "X-AKey" instead of "HTTP_X_AKEY"?**

(PS: For real applications, if both the client and server are negotiated to use the 'HTTP_xxx' format, there won't be any problem. I'm just curious about the answer for now.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"SomeValue" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SomeHeaderField"]

Comment: This is the way I add custom header "X-AKey", and it will be transformed to "HTTP_X_AKEY" as specified in my post

Comment: @Vishman sorry, but this answer is not correct for this question. Actually this line of code is what I was using, and it cannot create a http header field without a prefix of "HTTP_"

Comment: @DongMa I was recently started to build a Web API using PHP. So I had to use an FireFox extention, which is a REST API Client. So in that we can set HTTP Custom Headers. So let's say that I added an HTTP Header like "API-KEY" and it was received to the Server side as HTTP_API-KEY so that means HTTP automatically adds the Prefix of "HTTP_", and it's not something that we need to do within Obj-C or iOS Framework. 
Anyway let's say still you want to add that prefix explicitly? Then you can add it as the parameter for, forHTTPHeaderField:@"HTTP_Your-Custom-Header" right?

Comment: @Vishman yes, the solution is straight forward, when both sides are negotiated to use the form of "HTTP_" header filed for a real application. But my question is to ask if there is a way to by pass the 'implicit http field handling' by the underlying system or libraries. The question now doesn't intent to solve any issues, I'm just curious about the answer so far.